# QGIS: Select polygons from one layer which intersect/lie inside polygon from other layer?

Tags: qgis, intersection

I've got one polygon layer containing a lot of polygons (Layer 1 - red polygons) and a second layer with one polygon (Layer 2 - green area).

Now I want to select all polygons from Layer 1 which intersect/lie within the green polygon from Layer 2. **I DON'T want to have a new TEMP layer** containing the result of intersection - I rather want to have the polygons from layer 1 selected (or marked ... or whatever is possible) in order to assign a property to the affected polygons ....

In other words: I want to assign to all affected red polygons the property: "Lies (partyl) within green area" ...

How to do this within QGIS?

[image: How to select all red polygons which intersect green area?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Select By Location in Vector - Research tools
:

[image]

Change Geometric predicate to Intersect if you want all that also fall partly within.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for. Have looked over processing toolbox, but wasn't able to figure out, that this is the tool I was looking for

Comment: Great tool, just what I also needed. When I set it up and Run, it gives me this warning: "No spatial index exists for input layer, performance will be severely degraded." How do I resolve that?

Comment: Solved, created the Spatial Index in the layer before running this.